# Upload .m4a from Android to YouTube

Tags: audio, youtube

My teacher recorded his lectures on his Android phone in .m4a audio format, and would like to share them with the group on YouTube. Is there a free Android software that does just that?

Comment: For which OS? And in case of paid software, what's the price limit? Should it simply upload, or are there other features needed? Please [edit] your question and include those details.

Comment: You can probably use the ordinary web interface, or the official YouTube Android client. Or just transfer the videos to a PC first.

Comment: @Kodiologist these are audios, not videos, so all video editors that I've tried don't even allow to select them.

Comment: @AnatoliBabenia Oh, that's fair. I misread .m4a as .mp4. You probably need a different program to make videos out of your files first. On a PC, this can be done with avconv.